# How to expire FedAuth cookie at end of session when using trused identity provider

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, claims-based-auth

I've setup a custom trusted identity provider.  It logs the user into SharePoint just fine - however, the problem is that user *stays* logged in even after a browser restart.

The trusted identity provider website itself logs out, but SharePoint doesn't ask the identity provider to confirm login.

After some investigation it appears that for some reason SharePoint is setting the FedAuth cookie as a persistent cookie instead of a session cookie (whereas the identity provider set itself uses a session cookie).

How can I tell SharePoint to make the FedAuth cookie be a session cookie instead of a persistent cookie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With PowerShell:

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.UseSessionCookies = $true
$sts.Update()
iisreset
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh147183(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: It looks like this is global to the entire SharePoint installation - is that correct? (and if so can it be restricted to either a particular trusted identity provider, or to a particular web application?)

Comment: Yes, Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig returns security token service (STS) for the farm. I do not know any way to use sessions cookie for sinf=gle webb application.